# Convergent and bounded sequence of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Does a convergent and bounded sequence of positive semidefinite (psd) matrices always converge to a psd matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under the assumption that you talk about convergence in the topology induced by a matrix norm.

Then you have for an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $x^TA_nx \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and therefore the inequality also holds for the limit, thus $x^TAx \geq 0$.

Comment: But how do you know the limit is psd also?

Comment: I assumed that $A_n$ converges to $A$. So we have shown that $x^TAx \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which means that $A$ is psd.