# limit of sequence of positive definite matrix is positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\{A_n\}$ is a convergent sequence of positive definite matrices (i.e., $x^*A_nx>0$ for all $x\neq 0$), then is the limit positive semidefinite?

I'm realized this with the usual positive number sequence $\{a_n\}$ and the answer seem to be yes but I'm not sure how to start the matrix version.

Comment: All norms on the space of matrices are equivalent, so one such norm will tell you that for all vectors $x$, we have that $x^*A_nx \to x^*Ax$, where $A$ is the "limit" matrix. Then the assertion is obvious since the limit of a non-negative sequence remains non-negative.

Comment: The same is also the content of the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316902/convergent-and-bounded-sequence-of-positive-semidefinite-matrices). I am not sure if you're comfortable with the "change of norm", which is why I commented.

Comment: This uses continuity of matrix multiplication?

Comment: $$x^*A_nx=\sum_{i,j=1}^Na_n(ij)x_i\bar{x}_j \underset{n}{\longrightarrow}\sum_{i,j=1}^Na(ij)x_i\bar{x}_j=x^*Ax$$

Comment: Yes, it uses continuity of matrix multiplication. That is, the function $A \to x^*Ay$ is continuous for every fixed $x,y$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc this uses entrywise convergence? what's the norm used in that? componentwise absolute value?

Comment: @chhro All norms over the square matrices are topologically equivalent and lead to the conclusion that that convergence of a sequence of matrices is equivalent to entrywise convergence. If you really want to work with a norm though, I recommend the Frobenius norm $\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_{j,k}^n |a_{jk}|^2$.